# Is there a way to pull only one column of csv file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, file

I only need the first column

```
index                       A         B         C 
"11.08.2001 11:00:00"   12345   1234521    128984
"11.08.2001 12:00:00"   82345   1345216    432898
"11.08.2001 13:00:00"   52345   1234521    228984
"11.08.2001 14:00:00"   13345   1234521    128984
"11.08.2001 15:00:00"   12345   5934521    528984
"11.08.2001 16:00:00"   12345   9234521    628984
...                       ...       ...       ...
"11.08.2017 21:00:00"   12376   8712253    124556
```

The files are very large (sometimes 10GB) How to pull only the index RAM efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You sample set doesn't say if it is a csv or not. If it is, this should do the trick:

```
pd.read_csv(r"file.csv",usecols=[0])
```